# mongo native addToSet not working when update 2 fields at the same time

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

Mongo native addToSet not working when update 2 fields at the same time

This way NOT ok

```
db.Col.findAndModify(
    {_id: 'abcxyz123'}
    ,[['_id','descending']]
    ,{$addToSet:{field_1: 'aaa'}, $addToSet:{field_2: 'aaa'}}
    ,{new: true},
    function(err, result) {
        console.log(result.value) //field_1: [], field_2: ['aaa']   
        //It should be field_1: ['aaa'], field_2: ['aaa']
    });
```

This way works ok

```
db.Col.findAndModify(
    {_id: 'abcxyz123'}
    ,[['_id','descending']]
    ,{$addToSet:{field_1: 'aaa'}}
    ,{new: true},
    function(err, result) {
        console.log(result.value) //field_1: ['aaa'], field_2: []
        //It is ok          
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong the syntax for [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) is:

```
{ $addToSet: { <field1>: <value1>, ... } }
```

So here it is:

```
db.Col.findAndModify(
    ...
    { $addToSet: { field_1: 'aaa', field_2: 'aaa' }}
    ...
});
```